# Rails restful routes problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I've got two models: `Book` and `ReadingList`. A `ReadingList` `has_and_belongs_to_many` `Book`s. On the `BooksController#show` page, I'd like to have a select list that shows all the reading lists, with a button to add the current book to the selected reading list.

Presumably this should go to the `ReadingListController#update` action, but I can't specify this as the form's URL, because I won't know which ReadingList to send to at the time the form is created. I could hack it with JavaScript, but I'd rather not rely on that.

Would it be better to have a custom action in the `BooksController` that accepts a reading list id to add the book to, or can I work the routes so this request ends up getting to the `ReadingListController#update` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have a resource which is a ReadingListEntry that represents a book in a reading list. Then you can simply POST to that resource to add it. There doesn't actually need to be a model behind it, you can manipulate the reading list directly.

Comment: So many good ideas but I went for this one in the end - feels the most semantic. Cheers Anthony and everyone else :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is something that could easily be achieved by using Ajax to submit the form, but in the case where JavaScript is disabled / unavailable, your best option is to have a custom action in the BooksController that adds it to the required reading list.

You could combine both by having the form pointing to the action in the BooksController, but having an onsubmit handler that posts to the ReadingList controller via Ajax.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what would be achieved by having it go to a different controller with/without JS, apart from confusion :P Then again, JS might be a better option, as things like the default delete links only work with it enabled. I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom action and route such that you can provide a book_id and list_id and form the relation.

Assuming you're using restful routes

```
resources :books do 
  post '/lists/:list_id/subscribe' => 'lists#subscribe', :as => :subscribe
end

def subscribe 
  @list = List.find params[:list_id]
  @book = Book.find params[:book_id]
  @list << @book
end
```

Now you can use button_to with or without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a `has_many :through` relationship would be better? I like Anthony's idea of a ReadingListEntry resource - perhaps put a model behind this giving you:

```
# models/book.rb
has_many :reading_list_entries
has_many :reading_lists, :through => :reading_list_entries
```

Comment: Iiiinteresting.... If it turns out I need any logic to cover the join then that would make sense, but I think for now I just need the controller. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think here you are changing the `Book`, not the `ReadingList`. Therefore you should PUT to the BooksController#update resource with a new `list_id` attribute.

```
# in views/books/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @book, :url => book_path(@book) do |f| =>
  <%= f.select :list, ReadingList.all.map { |l| [l.name, l.id] } =>
  <%= submit_tag "Change" =>
<% end %>

# in controllers/books_controller.rb
# params[:book][:list_id] => 123
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :books
resources :lists do
  resources :books
end
```

If you wanted a Book to belong to more than one ReadingList you'd need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship instead

Comment: Sorry, you're right - it is actually a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. I'll update the question.